# Matlab sim command in parfor

Tags: matlab, simulink, parfor, parallel.for

I would like to run a Simulink model in a `parfor` loop on many cores with different data. However, I could not get the `sim` results when I use `parfor` whereas I can obtain them while using only for loop.

It simply get `[t,u]` from `workspace1`, consider a transfer function `n{1}/d{1}` and then calculates the `EqFracInt` to `workspace2`.

The problematic part of my code is

```
...
parfor ieq=1:1
    assignin('base','t',t);
    assignin('base','u',u);
    assignin('base','n',n);
    assignin('base','d',d);
    assignin('base','T_end',T_end);
    [simout] = sim('RespSpecFrac', [0 T_end], simset('ReturnWorkspaceOutputs','on'));
    PGRs = simout.get('EqFracInt');
end
```

I could not get the `PGRs` values. Could you please explain the error to me and how to solve it?

Comment: I don't see how your code is supposed to work. Maybe start with a for loop version, then try parfor.

Comment: There's lots of doc here http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html which might help you...

Answer (score 0):

The cause you can't get `PGRs` values is that is a temporary variable. Since in a `parfor` loop each iteration is independent, any variable assigned directly inside the loop without indexing is used only in that specific iteration and destroyed.
In order to get the desired values, you need to transform `PGRs` in either a sliced variable (by indexing it) or in a reduction variable (by, for example, concatenating it). Try to modify the last line of your loop following one of these examples:

```
   PGRs(ieq, :) = simout.get('EqFracInt');   % sliced variable
```

or

```
   PGRs = [PGRs; simout.get('EqFracInt')];   % reduction variable
```

The specific implementation will depend on the shape of the expected outputs `EqFracInt`, of course. You can see more about types of variables inside a `parfor` loop in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html#btfitu2-18).